# Why Spark Sql read same file twice in different stages for a single Action?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark sql code, I am reading a csv file of 1373 MB  in spark and  convert that as dataframe and create more than one temp tables. Each Temp table is derived from previous temp table.

When i execute the spark application using spark submit i see one job gets created , But when i go into Stages i see that two stages are reading the same input file. Why is it So?

I have only one Action . Why is the same input file is read twice in different stages by spark?
As you can see  there are 11 tasks being executed in Stage 0 and stage 2 with same input file size.

**[image: Attaching the spark UI :]**

**Spark Code :** Only some part of Code is here.

```
    object OmegaETL extends BaseETL {
            def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

             val omega_hdfs_input_loc ="/user/cloudera/data/inputfiles/Omega_events.csv"


             val sc                      = getSparkContext(jobName)
             val sqlContext              = getHiveContext(sc)
             val omegaRDD        = getBaseRDD(sc,omega_hdfs_input_loc)

             val OmegaoutputDF   = doOmegaProcess(sc,sqlContext,omegaRDD)

             OmegaoutputDF.registerTempTable("Omega_processed")
             sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Omega_processed LIMIT 20 ").show(20)  
         }


          def doOmegaProcess(sc:SparkContext, sqlContext: HiveContext, OmegaRDD:RDD[Array[String]]): DataFrame = {
           import sqlContext.implicits._

             log.info("doOmegaProcess method started")
             val schemaRDD       = OmegaRDD.map(arr => new Omega(arr(0),arr(1),arr(2),arr(3),arr(4),
                                                      arr(5),arr(6),arr(7),arr(8),arr(9)))

             val OmegaDF        = schemaRDD.toDF()
             val Omega_filterDF = OmegaDF.filter($"scheme_name".isNotNull &&  length(trim($"scheme_name"))  > 0)
             Omega_filterDF.registerTempTable("Omega_filtered")
            //sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from Omega_filtered LIMIT 10").show(5)
             val latestEventDF   = getLatestEvent(sc,sqlContext,Omega_filterDF)// This line does further transformation on Omega_filterDF alone.
             latestEventDF.registerTempTable("Omega_latest_event")
             //sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from Omega_latest_event LIMIT 10").show(10)

             val OmegaoutputDF  = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT *

                                       |FROM Omega_filtered
                                       |WHERE TRIM(event_type) ='ACTION')Omega_events
                                       |INNER JOIN
                                       |Omega_latest_event
                                       |ON(Omega_events.data_id= Omega_latest_event.data_idAND Omega_events.conversion_base_type = Omega_latest_event.conversion_base_type)
                                       |""".stripMargin)// In this query I am applying union on two temp tables. Not including the whole query in question as it is big
             log.info("doOmegaProcess method ended")
              OmegaoutputDF
           }


       }

 class BaseETL {
 def getBaseRDD(sc:SparkContext,fileLoc:String):RDD[String]={
   sc.textFile(fileLoc)

  }
}
```

Could some one help me on why same file is read twice by spark? How to overcome this?

Is it happening because of multiple temp tables that I am creating?

Comment: What is `getBaseRDD` doing? Also, how are you passing in your sparkContext when it is declared below your omegaRdd?

Comment: It is copy paste issue .. GetBaseRDD  creates parent RDD for file  Updated the question

Comment: Have you figured out the solution for the problem?